# Grails exceptions filtering, RabbitMQ plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, rabbitmq

grails is filtering exceptions and show only related errors.
how to get exceptions thrown in handleMessage of rabbitmq on console?
For example, simple consuming service with Division by zero operation. I want to see all exceptions happened in handleMessage on the console.

```
class SimpleService {
  static rabbitSubscribe = 'test'
  void handleMessage(message) {
        def a = 10/0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite short, so I'm assuming a lot. Do you mean that you're using 2.0 and seeing the truncated stacktraces in run-app? You can add the `--stacktrace` and/or `-verbose` commandline options to see more output, e.g.

```
grails run-app --stacktrace -verbose
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't help